# Android App crashes on startup with nothing changed..?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, crash, oncreate

[SOLVED] -> NullPointerException was not caused in Java, but by an outside source (WCF webservice) with faulty implementation.

I have an Android App project in Android Studio that I had working perfectly fine a few days ago. I came into work today, literally changing *nothing* and when I launch it now, it just crashes on startup. I really don't understand what the stacktrace is trying to tell me..

```
                                             [ 08-21 16:59:35.445  8492: 
8492 D/         ]
                                             HostConnection::get() New Host 
Connection established 0xa279c3c0, tid 8492


                                             [ 08-21 16:59:35.499  8492: 
8520 D/         ]
                                             HostConnection::get() New Host 
Connection established 0xa279c740, tid 8520
08-21 16:59:35.559 8492-8492/com.example.pmatthews.appointmentcreator 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.pmatthews.appointmentcreator, PID: 8492

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'java.lang.String[] java.lang.String.split(java.lang.String)' on a null 
object reference

at 



com.example.pmatthews.appointmentcreator.
appointments$GetConNum.onPostExecute(ap
pointments.java:142)

at 

  com.example.pmatthews.appointmentcreator.
appointments$GetConNum.onPostExecute(appointments.java:71)

at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:667)

at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)

at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:684)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at 



com.android.internal.os.
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
08-21 16:59:36.728 2155-2243/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search 
E/AudioRecord: Could not get audio input for session 897, record source 
1999, sample rate 16000, format 0x1, channel mask 0x10, flags 0
08-21 16:59:36.731 2155-2243/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search 
E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check 
failed with status -22.
08-21 16:59:36.731 2155-2243/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search 
E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native 
AudioRecord object.
08-21 16:59:36.731 2155-2243/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search 
E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for 
com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
```

startup activity- appointments.java:

```
class GetConNum extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String status = null;
    Activity context;
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    TextView txtV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtConNum);
    TextView txtV1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtConNum1);
    TextView txtV2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtConNum2);
    TextView txtV3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtConNum3);
    TextView txtV4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtConNum4);
    TextView txtV5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtConNum5);
    TextView txtV6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtConNum6);
    TextView txtV7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtConNum7);
    TextView txtV8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtConNum8);
    TextView txtV9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtConNum9);
    TextView txtV10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtConNum10);
    TextView txtV11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtConNum11);
    TextView txtV12 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtConNum12);
    TextView txtV13 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtConNum13);
    TextView txtV14 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtConNum14);
    TextView txtV15 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtConNum15);
    TextView txtV16 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtConNum16);
    TextView txtV17 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtConNum17);
    TextView txtV18 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtConNum18);
    TextView txtV19 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtConNum19);

    public GetConNum(Activity context, ListView listView){
        this.context = context;
        this.listView = listView;
    }

    public void onPreExecute(){

    }
    public String doInBackground(String... connUrl){
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        BufferedReader reader;

        try{
            final URL url = new URL(connUrl[0]);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; 
charset=utf-8");
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            int result = conn.getResponseCode();
            if(result == 200){



                InputStream in = new 
BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                String line = null;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    status = line;
                    res = res + result;

                }

            }

        }catch(Exception ex){

        }
        return status;

    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        String[] resultArray = result.split(",");

        if (resultArray.length == 0){

        }else if (resultArray.length == 1) {
            txtV.setText(resultArray[0].replaceAll("
[[{}]]","").replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", 
"").replaceAll("\"","").replaceAll(":", " : 
").replaceAll("/","").replaceAll("00 
: 00 AM", ""));
        }else if (resultArray.length == 2){
```

Comment: Your error is a NullPointerException on a String array (specifically, one that was formed through a String.split()). Does your app pull external data? It could be that data was edited.

Comment: Yes it pulls data from a database and I checked, all the data seems the same. It queries SELECT TOP 20 FROM Table

Comment: Please post the code leading up to and including the String.split()

Comment: Also, I would recommend running the debugger with a break point before the split to see what is going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `AsyncTask`.
You are trying to split a null `String`.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
>   'java.lang.String[] java.lang.String.split(java.lang.String)' on a null 
>   object reference

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out thanks to you two pointing out something I somehow failed to miss: the string was null. In the debugger I was getting a getresponsecode of 400 so I checked the web service in Google Chrome and surprise surprise, instead of getting the data, I got an exception. I went in Visual Studio and got rid of the not implement exception and configured it to run the method instead. Works like a charm. Thank you all :)